# get_template_part in admin

Tags: admin, get-template-part

I am trying to use get_template_part when creating a page in the admin section of my site. However, it does not seem to be working.  Does this function not work in the admin section?  What alternative can I use?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [get_template_part()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) does work on Admin pages. Here is how I tested:

Add this to functions.php theme (or child theme) file:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_99662_register_admin_test_page' );

function wpse_99662_register_admin_test_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Admin Test Page',
        'Admin Test Page',
        'manage_options',
        'admin_test_page',
        'wpse_99662_admin_test_page'
    );
}

function wpse_99662_admin_test_page() {
    echo '<h2>Admin Test Page</h2>';

    get_template_part( 'admin', 'test' );
}
```

The `admin-test.php` file contains the following:

```
<?php

echo "Loaded admin-test.php<br />";
```

Comment: I was using it like this - <?php get_template_part( THEME_DIRECTORY . 'includes/test-components/test-badge' ); ?> - so I just passed in a single parameter with the full path - is that a problematic syntax?

Comment: get_template_part) hands its result to [locate_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) which is already checking inside STYLESHEETPATH and TEMPLATEPATH for each file name. So, now you are checking for another THEME_DIRECTORY inside each of those directories which probably doesn't exist. For that case, `locate_template()` silently fails. Try: `get_template_part( 'includes/test-components/test-badge' );`